# GridView is not binding C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, syncfusion

I am using GridView and trying to bind data to this GridView, but I am facing unusual problem, here is my code :

Method to bind GridView :

```
private void BindDataSource()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new         SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
        string queryString6 = "";
        string items = "";
        if (lb_add_col.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem listItem in lb_add_col.Items)
            {
                if (listItem.Selected == true)
                {
                    items += listItem.Text + ",";
                }
            }
        }
        items = items.TrimEnd(',');
        queryString6 = "SELECT "+items+" from " +ddl_tables.Items[0].Text;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCmd6 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString6, con);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter6 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd6);
        System.Data.DataSet dataSet6 = new System.Data.DataSet();
        dataAdapter6.Fill(dataSet6);
        string[] columns = items.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            order.Add(new Orders(columns.Contains("id") ? Convert.ToInt32(dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"]) : 0, columns.Contains("name") ? dataSet6.Tables
            [0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString() : "N/A", columns.Contains("month") ? dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows[i]["month"].ToString() : "N/A", columns.Contains("effiecency") ? Convert.ToInt32(dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows[i]
            ["effiecency"]) : 0, columns.Contains("latitude") ? Convert.ToInt32(dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows[i]["latitude"]) : 0, columns.Contains("longitude") ? Convert.ToInt32(dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows[i]
            ["longitude"]) : 0));

        }

        this.OrdersGrid.DataSource = order;
        this.OrdersGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

From above method order is showing the data but GridView is not binding.

Button Click event on which I am calling this method :

```
protected void btn_add_col_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models.Column sd;
        foreach (ListItem listItem in lb_add_col.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected == true)
            {

                sd = new Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models.Column();
                if (listItem.Text == "id")
                {
                    sd.IsPrimaryKey = true;
                }
                sd.Field = listItem.Text;
                sd.HeaderText = listItem.Value;
                sd.Width = 90;
                sd.TextAlign = Syncfusion.JavaScript.TextAlign.Right;
                this.OrdersGrid.Columns.Add(sd);
            }
        }

        BindDataSource();
    }
```

Comment: have you debug your code that your "order" is containing some value after the for loop?

Comment: yes I have checked and it always shows some values after loop but when I assign this 'order' as DataSource then GridView is not binding.

Comment: is order is your generic list?and where are you calling this code? on page load?

Comment: yes order is generic list and I have made a method to bind GridView and I am calling this method on Button click event.

Comment: did u check with a break point to make sure the data is coming from database?

Comment: can u put your full code?

Comment: @Arun Prasanth I have updated my query, now I think it will easy to understand.

Comment: @neeraj Could you define any columns for Grid in aspx or in page load method?

Answer (score 1):

If the order contains value after the loop has executed then the data source will be bind to the Grid. But the Grid does not contain the columns that you have defined in the button click, it return all columns in the grid data source. the Grid has only shown the column that you have define in the bindDataSource method,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you post a suggestion of how the code should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

if `dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows.Count` is zero, the GridView will databind but there will be no data.

Comment: No dataSet6.Tables[0].Rows.Count is always greater than 0.

Comment: @NeerajPurohit One other thing to try, is AutoGenerateColumns set to true?

Comment: Actually I am using third party tool and in their GridView control "AutoGenerateColumns" property is not exist.

Comment: Well for goodness sake, you wasted a lot of people's time.   Put the vendor name of the third party control in your list of tags.

Comment: Actually I thought its binding problem, is there any connection with the control??